# Powering a Micro-controller & PC Fan by a single DC adapter

Tags: fan, rp2040

Motivations:
I want to power a microcontroller & 5V-PWM 12V-DC fan simultaneously with a 12V, 6W wall-power supply. This set-up is to form a cheap speed controlled Solder-fume extractor.

- PSU:  [6W 12Vdc](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/ac-dc-adapters/1753294)
- Fan: [Noctua P12 1700RPM](https://noctua.at/en/nf-p12-redux-1700-pwm/specification)
- Driver IC: [MCP14A0302](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2724282.pdf) (probably will have to place in series in the PWM stage as Pico output is 3.3V and fan needs 5V, also powered by VCC of Pico)

[image: Circuit diagram]
My motivations for component choices are as follows:
R3-100R to set the max current to 120mA to fan.
R1/R2 to set max current to the Pico at 10mA (although maybe this should be raised to 100mA)

My question is, is this circuit going to work? Do I need to consider protections against the back-emf from the fan, like a fly-back. I want the cheapest and simplest method for powering the fan with speed control.

Speed control is more of an academic project.. obviously the simplest way is to get a fixed speed fan and power it without a MCU.

Answer (score 0):

> *My question is, is this circuit going to work?*

- R1 and R2 is a bad idea. Use a voltage regulator that provides the pico with a steady and stable power supply voltage.
- R3 is a bad idea. The maximum fan current is 90 mA and, if this flows through 120 &oh;, the fan only gets 1.2 volts and the resistor dissipated about 1 watt.

> *My motivations for component choices are as follows: R3-100R to set
> the max current to 120mA to fan.*

Your motivation appears unjustified.

Answer (score 0):

For the VCC of the raspberry pi you need a 5 volt power supply rail. I would suggest using a DC to DC converter that can convert 12 volts to 5 volts.

You should not put a hundred ohm resistor in between 12 volts and the fan if you are using pwm control, there is no reason to slow down the fan if you are controlling it with pwm and the resistor will heat up. The pwm should be sufficient to control the fan speed.

No flyback diodes are needed because you're not switching the fan on and off

What is not clear to me is if the pwm needs 5V logic levels or 3.3 volt logic levels. If the fan needs 5 volts you may need to use a 3.3 v to 5V level shifter circuit